# Why can prior be swamped? (given a data set, any prior will go to the same posterior)

Tags: bayesian

Is there any mathematical proof for that?

Comment: Where did you find this statement?

Comment: In a book named "Think Bayes". My statement might not be accurate in the mathematical sense, but it was a rough idea I got from the book, which says like "the convergence of posterior distribution".